# How can I tell if someone copies files through VPN

Tags: vpn, file-transfer

If someone is connected through VPN on a server is it possible to tell if he is copying and pasting files (from server on their computer) inside a Remote Desktop Connection session?

Comment: If you control the VPN server, you can observe bandwidth on RDP port to guess that. You can disable file transfer in terminal server as well...

Answer (score 2):

If someone is connected through VPN to your network it acts like he was in the Local Area Network. So the main question is:

> Can we tell if someone is copying a file from the LAN?

Theoretically there should be a way to filter this with a program called [Wire Shark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (or similar)

---

What You should do is filter NFS traffic:

> Display Filter
>
> A complete list of NFS display filter fields can be found in the
>   display [filter reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/n/nfs.html)
>
> Show only the NFS traffic:
>   `nfs`
>
> You cannot directly filter NFS while capturing. However, if you know
>   the port used (see above), you can filter on that one.
>
> `Capture NFS traffic over the default port (2049)`

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Network_File_System

---

**Edit**:
I have found a more in-depth answer here on Super User that confirms and completes my theory:

[How to record traffic which is inside a VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/882007/how-to-record-traffic-which-is-inside-a-vpn)

---

After some further research, I found that there is a more ideal software for this purpose called [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

> HOW TO: Capture network traffic on the VPN Server
>
> We recommend using Microsoft Network Monitor when capturing network
>   traffic on the VPN Server, this since Network Monitor seems to be
>   better at intercepting all traffic from the VPN Server filter.
>
> Wireshark only seems to capture packets sent to the VPN Server not
>   from the VPN Server.
>
> The Network Monitor capture file format can be used by Wireshark so
>   the capture can be viewed using Wireshark if you prefer that.

---

> Network Monitor Quick Guide
>
> Create display filer for specific IP address:
>
> -under the Capture tab  -in the Display Filter window  -select Load
>   Filter->Standard Filters->Adresses->IPv4 Adresses  -modify
>   "IPv4.Address ==" to the address you are interested in and press Apply
>
> To show IP addresses not host names in captures:
>
> -under the Capture tab  -in the Frame Summary window  -select
>   Columns->Choose Columns...  -replace "Source" with "Source Network
>   Address" and "Destination" with "Destination Network Address"

Comment: AFAIK, VPN tunnels are encrypted so WireShark won't do much in this case.

Comment: @nkn - If I am right, VPN is only encrypted while it is on the internet.